# Issue with a Canvas ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I'm trying to implement the example shown here [ [WPF Canvas, how to add children dynamically with MVVM code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913792/wpf-canvas-how-to-add-children-dynamically-with-mvvm-code-behind) ], but nothing is shown when I launch my program (even with IsItemHost set to True for the Canvas.

My application is made of an Entity type :

```
public class Entity
{
    public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

The entities are stored in an EntitiesCollection :

```
public class EntitiesCollection : ObservableCollection<Entity>
{
    public EntitiesCollection()
    {
        Add(new Entity(10, 10, 10, 10));
        Add(new Entity(50, 20, 25, 25));
    }
}
```

Wich is a member of a a DrawingViewModel class :

```
public class DrawingViewModel
{
    public DrawingViewModel()
    {
        Entities = new EntitiesCollection();
    }

    public EntitiesCollection Entities;
}
```

The DataContext for my application is set in MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new DrawingViewModel();
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml file itself looks like this :

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="Graphics/Icons/paint.png">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What's wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, `Entity` should either provide no public setters/no setters at all and `private readonly` backing fields or implement  [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). So that either the properties do not change at all or that the UI is notified of changes.

Comment: Turning the field into a Property did not solve the issue : nothing appears when I launch the program. An I agree for the INotifyPropertyChanged, but this was just the first step :)

Comment: So do you have any binding errors?

Comment: I'm pretty new to binding debugging yet, but nothing is mentionned when I simply launch the program in debug mode.

Comment: Did you read the article i linked to? You won't get any exceptions from failed bindings...

Comment: Apparently I made something wrong when I changer the field to a property the first time, since it is now working. Sorry for that and thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Entities` has to be a property instead of a field. (There should be respective [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).)