# Passing an UIElement to the ViewModel using RelayCommand from MVVM-Light

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

In the start-screen of my program I am showing thumbnails of a (non-interactive) UserControl `DocumentView` to display different documents inside a Tile-like UserControl `LoadTileView`, on which the user can click to load the document into the main view. This `DocumentView` is also used in the main view to graphically represent and edit the selected document. Since this `DocumentView` is graphically heavy, it takes some time to load, which causes a huge startup time, since I am showing multiple instances of the `DocumentView` inside the start-screen (e.g. various Tiles from which the user can select, which Document to edit).

I am therefore working on a way to save a cached image of the `DocumentView` instance that belongs to each `LoadingTileView`, so that it can be shown instead of the actual `DocumentView`, when my program is started the next time.

I am currently working out how to save the cache images. My idea is to have the each `LoadTileView` call its `LoadingTileViewModel` via a MVVM-Light `RelayCommand` once it is loaded and pass its instance of `DocumentView` to the command. I put `DocumentView` inside a DataTemplate so that I can replace it with the its cached image (and corresponding View), once it exists by setting `CurrentDocumentViewModel` accordingly in `LoadingTileView`.

I have found an explanation on how to pass a `UIElement` to the ViewModel [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693516/saving-a-wpf-canvas-as-an-image-following-mvvm-pattern) and how to use the `RelayCommand` with an argument [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298910/mvvm-light-relaycommand-parameters). Combined with blender interaction-triggers to fire the `ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand` in the ViewModel came up with the reduced code shown below.

This code compile and runs, but `parameter` in `ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand(object parameter)` is `Null`. I have also tried using `DocumentView` directly, instead of the `ContentControl`, but `parameter` is still `Null`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, since I have used `RelayCommand` and the `Interaction.Triggers` this in other cases, where they worked correctly. Perhaps somebody can spot my error?

Code for **LoadingTileView**:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
        <View:DocumentView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DocumentViewInstance}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Controls:Tile Command="{Binding LoadProgramCommand}">
    <Viewbox>
        <ContentControl x:Name="DocumentViewInstance" Content="{Binding CurrentDocumentViewModel}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Controls:Tile>
```

Code for **LoadingTileViewModel**:

```
public LoadingTileViewModel()
{
    ...
    ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((obj)=>ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand(obj));
    ...
}

public RelayCommand<object> ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand { get; set; }
private void ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand(object parameter) // object is NULL
{
    UIElement toSave = (UIElement)parameter;
    //OnViewLoaded();
}
```

**Update:**

Stacktrace, when breaking at line `UIElement toSave = (UIElement)parameter;`:

```
Software.UI.ViewModel.dll!ProgramEditor.ViewModel.LoadingTileViewModel.ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand(object parameter) Line 168  C#
Software.UI.ViewModel.dll!ProgramEditor.ViewModel.LoadingTileViewModel.get_ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand.AnonymousMethod__50_0(object i) Line 184   C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll!GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction<System.__Canon>.Execute(System.__Canon parameter)  Unknown
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll!GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object>.Execute(object parameter)    Unknown
System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction.Invoke(object parameter)  Unknown
System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(object parameter)   Unknown
System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(System.EventArgs eventArgs)  Unknown
System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(System.Windows.DependencyObject root, System.Windows.RoutedEvent routedEvent)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(object root) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork() Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks() Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(object resizedCompositionTarget)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(object resizedCompositionTarget)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
user32.dll!74d862fa()   Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]    
user32.dll!74d86d3a()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86ded()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86e4c()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!773a011a()    Unknown
user32.dll!74d872c1()   Unknown
user32.dll!74dad4ff()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d862fa()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86d3a()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d90d37()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d90d5d()   Unknown
WindowsBase.ni.dll!6b4a6e70()   Unknown
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
user32.dll!74d862fa()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86d3a()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d90d37()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d90d5d()   Unknown
WindowsBase.ni.dll!6b4ced1a()   Unknown
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
user32.dll!74d862fa()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86d3a()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86ded()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86ded()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d88fb7()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!773a011a()    Unknown
user32.dll!74d92832()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d92802()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d9289a()   Unknown
[Managed to Native Transition]  
MahApps.Metro.dll!Standard.NativeMethods.SetWindowRgn(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw) Unknown
MahApps.Metro.dll!Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._SetRoundingRegion(Standard.WINDOWPOS? wp) Unknown
MahApps.Metro.dll!Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._UpdateFrameState(bool force)  Unknown
MahApps.Metro.dll!Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._ApplyNewCustomChrome()    Unknown
MahApps.Metro.dll!Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._WindowSourceInitialized(object sender, System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.OnSourceInitialized(System.EventArgs e) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(bool duringShow) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(object booleanBox)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
user32.dll!74d862fa()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d86d3a()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d877d3()   Unknown
user32.dll!74d8789a()   Unknown
WindowsBase.ni.dll!6b4ceff4()   Unknown
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
ProgramEditor.exe!ProgramEditor.App.Main()  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
mscoreei.dll!7143cc0b() Unknown
mscoree.dll!714b7f16()  Unknown
mscoree.dll!714b4de3()  Unknown
kernel32.dll!76d6338a() Unknown
ntdll.dll!773c9902()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!773c98d5()    Unknown
```

Comment: If you are setting LoadingTileView's DataContext in the constructor then make sure you do this *before* the call to InitializeComponent().

Comment: I'd say, if the Binding to the Command works the DataContext is there, so that's not it. I actually think the code looks ok... How does the stacktrace look like when you hit `ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand` maybe you'll find a hint about where it goes wrong...

Comment: @MarkusHütter Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately the callstack does not give me much enlightenment. See below. Perhaps you have another suggestion?

`LoadingTileViewModel.ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand(object parameter)

LoadingTileViewModel..ctor.AnonymousMethod__24_0(object obj)

[External Code]

[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]`

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/11/did-you-know-how-to-show-external-code-288/

Comment: @packoman instead of `{Binding ElementName=DocumentViewInstance}`, write only `someinput` and see it reaches `ExecuteViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand` .

Comment: @MarkusHütter Thanks for the heads-up. Added the StackTrace to the question.
@AnjumSKhan Doing what you describe, `someinput` reaches the command. Thanks for the idea BTW!

Comment: *reads the title* that's not mvvm.  Save yourself headache and move your saving code into the codebehind.

Comment: @Will This is an excellent point, that I had not considered. I got my code working for the moment, but I should clean it up to be more in line with the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was, that the `Loaded` event of the `TileView` fired *before* the `DocumentView` inside the DataTemplate loaded. I found this out by attaching another Command in my `DocumentViewModel` to the `Loaded` event of the `DocumentView`. Afterwards I saw Markus' answer and this is essentially what he suggested.

In the end I got my code working by moving the command for the `Loaded` event to the DataTemplate. For this I used a `StackPanel` to bind to its `Loaded` event, so that I ended up with:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <View:DocumentView x:Name="DocumentViewInstance"/>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewLoadedEventHandlerCommand,
                                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DocumentViewInstance}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you @packoman for the suggestion. I was able to retrieve the Button control in my RelayCommand parameter. This worked for me :- `<Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding _MyRelayCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyButton} />`

Answer (score 0):

in the comments you say that `someinput` reaches the command. That means the elementname binding is either failing entirely or late.

So: for testing, add a `Button` that has the same `i:InvokeCommandAction` but on an `<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">` that way you can test if a later Binding will work.

Also keep an eye on the *Output* window in VS while debugging. If the binding fails there should be a message.

My assumption is that the problem is within your `Tile` control. I'd guess your Tile control hasn't initialized its child elements yet when the `Loaded` event happens.

Comment: Yes in the end, this is was the case. As describe in my answer, the DataTemplate is being initialized after the `Tile` control. I wonder, whether this is default behavior for a `ContentControl`?