# WPF-Canvas doesn't show bound items of ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, itemscontrol

I am working on a small state chart editor.
I try to implement it in the MVVM pattern.

What I got so far:

My main view

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:StateChartViewModel x:Key="StateChartViewModel"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StateViewModel}">
        <views:StateWidget/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TransitionViewModel}">
        <views:TransitionWidget/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Canvas Background="Transparent"
        DataContext="{StaticResource StateChartViewModel}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  CreateStateCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <ItemsControl Canvas.Left="0"
                  Canvas.Top="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Transitions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Canvas.Left="0"
                  Canvas.Top="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding States}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>

</Canvas>
```

The DataTemplates which I have set for the StateViewModel and the TransitionViewModel are views of these viewModels

StateView (StateWidget)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:StateViewModel x:Key="StateViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="XMainGrid"
      DataContext="{StaticResource StateViewModel}">
    <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" 
               RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" 
               ClipToBounds="True">
    </Rectangle>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=State.Name}" 
                 Background="Transparent"/>            
        <Polygon Points="0,0 20,0 10,10" 
                 Fill="DarkSlateGray" 
                 Margin="10,5,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

TransitionView (TransitionWidget)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:TransitionViewModel x:Key="TransitionViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource TransitionViewModel}">
    <Line X1="{Binding SourceState.Position.X}"
          Y1="{Binding SourceState.Position.Y}"
          X2="{Binding TargetState.Position.X}"
          Y2="{Binding TargetState.Position.Y}"
          Stroke="DarkGreen"
          StrokeThickness="4"
          />
</Canvas>
```

In the StateChartViewModel I have 2 ObservableCollections with StateViewModels and TransitionModels

```
    private ObservableCollection<StateViewModel> _states;
    public ObservableCollection<StateViewModel> States
    {
        get
        {
            if (_states == null)
                _states = new ObservableCollection<StateViewModel>();

            return _states;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TransitionViewModel> _transitions;
    public ObservableCollection<TransitionViewModel> Transitions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_transitions == null)
                _transitions = new ObservableCollection<TransitionViewModel>();

            return _transitions;
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs> _createStateCommand; 
    public ICommand CreateStateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_createStateCommand == null)
                _createStateCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(AddNewState);

            return _createStateCommand;
        }
    }

    private void AddNewState(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var newState = new StateViewModel();
        _states.Add(newState);
    }
```

My problem is that the canvas in the main view doesn't show any of that items when I add StateViewModels to States aswell with the transitions. When adding SateWidgets directly to the canvas' children they are appear in the canvas. But I think there have to be a solution without doing it manually.

### Edit

The StateView (StateWidget) and the TransitionView (TransitionWidget) should both be displayed in the same canvas!
StateViewModels should be displayed as StateWidgets and TransitionViewModels as Transitionwidgets.

```
  MainCanvas

  /--------------\    TransitionWidget    /--------------\
  | StateWidget1 |------------------------| StateWidget2 |
  \--------------/                        \--------------/
```

Comment: Hi you are both setting datacontext on your StateView and your TransistionView, and at the sametime you have A collection of these stored in a different vm. Remove the datacontext from the StateView and TransistionView, so the items in the lists are set as datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

In your AddNewState method in your vm OnPropertyChanged("States") is redundant, as OC notifies the ui when you add or remove items. But you have something wrong in your views there:

**StateView**

```
<Grid x:Name="XMainGrid">
   <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" 
           RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" 
           ClipToBounds="True">
   </Rectangle>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10">
       <!-- Use twoway if you want to your binding to post back to your vm -->
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=State.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Background="Transparent"/>            
       <Polygon Points="0,0 20,0 10,10" 
                Fill="DarkSlateGray" 
               Margin="10,5,0,0"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**TransitionView:**

```
<Canvas>
   <Line X1="{Binding SourceState.Position.X}"
      Y1="{Binding SourceState.Position.Y}"
      X2="{Binding TargetState.Position.X}"
      Y2="{Binding TargetState.Position.Y}"
      Stroke="DarkGreen"
      StrokeThickness="4"/>
</Canvas>
```

There now you are inherhiting the datacontext from the list items, rather than creating a new viewmodel as datacontext for each item in the list, which I think is your issue here. BTW These ViewModels for the two mentioned views, are they datamodels? Be sure to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in all nested classes. Have you considered using a ViewModelLocator BTW?
I'm quite fond of GalaSoft MVVM Light.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your answer. Of course, the OnPropertyChanges call is redundant. I tried your changes, but this doesn't change anything. The ViewModels have a property to the datamodels and all ViewModels extends my BaseViewModel which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. Where do the views get their data from if I don't set the dataContext?

Comment: @Zarzan Great to to see you do things so nice as you describe there, always good to hear! :) Unfortunately I'm in a bit of a rush here, so I can't recreate your project right now. [There is a similar case here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5914970/2285592). The datacontext should be inherhited from your StateChartViewModel, or well in your itemscontrol each item will be given the datacontext of the item in the list.

Comment: I edited my question a bit so that it should be clearer what want.
I thought the ViewModelLocator is for displaying different ViewModels but not at the same time? Or is it also useful in my case?